# Is it better to use a reference to a dom element inside a callback instead of retrieving it?

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure how to phrase this question concisely, so if it's been asked before (and I'm sure it has been) that's why I can't find the answer(s).

If I have something like the following code in Javascript/jQuery:

```
$('#my-clicky-thing').click(function() {
    if ( document.getElementById('my-checkbox').checked ){
        // whatever
    }
}
```

...would it be more sensible / efficient to do this instead:

```
var myCheckbox = document.getElementById('my-checkbox');
$('#my-clicky-thing').click(function() {
    if ( myCheckbox.checked ){
        // whatever
    }
}
```

The latter approach seems to me like it would be more efficient. I'm assuming that a reference to the checkbox is bound to the click callback function when it is created, so using the checkbox reference would be faster than having to call getElementById to fetch it.

I'm just using this as a simple example. I don't have any formal Javascript training, but in practice, I usually always go with the reference approach. I just never stopped to think if there are any drawbacks or gotchas with doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The latter approach seems to me like it would be more efficient.

That depends on what you mean by "efficient." It's less memory-efficient, for instance. But unless you have millions of them, the memory impact is unlikely to matter.

> I'm assuming that a reference to the checkbox is bound to the click callback function when it is created...

Yes, it is, because the callback is a closure over the context in which that variable exists.

> ... so using the checkbox reference would be faster than having to call getElementById to fetch it.

***Infinitesimally***, yes. `getElementById` is **very** fast, because the browser keeps an index of elements by their ID and so it's a very, very, very quick lookup.

A more complex DOM query would be slower, but `click`s are nothing like time-sensitive, so it's extremely unlikely to matter. A slow query in relation to an event that happens a **lot** (like `mousemove`) would argue for caching the reference; otherwise, it really doesn't matter and the decision of whether to keep the reference vs. looking it up is probably best driven by other factors, such as whether the element may go away, whether the closure will otherwise be optimized away (e.g., nothing else in it), that sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

You are definitely correct. Looking for the element in the DOM on every click is less efficient using jQuery's $() (see note). Keeping a reference to it is always a good practice.

It is especially recommended if you are planning to look for it more than once and perform several actions on it.

The only drawback I can think of is that when done excessively you'll end up having lots of variables sitting around holding references.. So this one is up to you to consider in your implementation.

For example, if you have a lot of these elements that need to be referenced, hold a reference to their container instead of to each one of them. Finding them within their container is likely to be more efficient than searching the entire DOM.

Note: As @T.J.Crowder mentioned, getElementByID is fairly fast and you shouldn't worry about it in this case. My answer is general and especially referring the $() selector for jQuery.

Comment: *"Looking for the element in the DOM on every click is highly inefficient. "* Not with `getElementById` it isn't. Clicks are nothing like time-sensitive.

Comment: You are right about performance, but those issues aside, it somehow doesn't feel right to me to use the DOM as sort of a huge global bag of elements that you look for things inside every time you turn around. I much prefer the approach of holding elements in variables, all else being equal.

Comment: @YotamOmer I'd just change "highly inefficient" to "less efficient", and "lot more efficient" to "a bit more efficient".

Comment: @torazaburo you are right, no room here for exaggeration :) It really depends on the situation and the rest of the DOM etc..

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of general rule imo : keep reference to object as long as you may require access to this object though it's different for Java/C# where garbage collector removes all objects that does not have references so if you keep reference to object - you keep object in memory even when you don't need it.

But in your case i believe it doesn't really matter as click is event that fires too rare to make big difference. It would make more sense if you would like to access 50 different dom elements like 10 000 times each.

Comment: Your understanding of GC is a bit shaky. A variable holding a reference to a DOM element will definitely be garbage collected once it goes out of scope, just like any other variable.